# process.start from a variable location %temp%

Tags: environment-variables, process.start, temp

I have the program unzipping the file to %temp%\myfolder\

I need to run a file from within that location.
I have tried both shell and process.start but ultimately I'm looking for:

```
Process.start("%temp%\myfolder\start.cmd")
```

Also I looked on msdn on the getenvironmentvariable but nothing has worked. :(

**Update: This is what I have in a nutshell**

```
Imports system.diagnostics
Imports system.IO

System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")
Dim temp As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath

Things I have tried
process.start("%temp%\myfolder\start.cmd")
process.start("temp" & "myfolder\start.cmd")
```

I get an error code saying "file not found". But if I copy %temp%\myfolder\start.cmd into run or cmd.exe the program runs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944483/how-to-get-temporary-folder-for-current-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set the

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp")
' Possible variables include temp, tmp, and windir for examples.
```

This command will place the current directory as C:\Users\ (currentuser)\appdata\local\temp or which ever the variable is set for. Then run process start. It should look like this:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp")
Process.start("myfolder\start.cmd")
```