# Is there a wildcard for file paths?

Tags: c#, file, download, path, sftp

I'm working on a project that downloads an exe file via sftp in C# using `Tamir.SharpSSH`. It works however I want it to be downloaded in appdata/local/temp. The current filepath i'm using is

```
    C:/Users/Pavilion/AppData/Local/Temp/Project.exe
```

But not everyones computer is called "Pavilion" Is there some kind of wildcard I can use?

Comment: Wildcards are used when searching. You're just looking for a way to find the temp directory for the current user, which is answered in [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944483/how-to-get-temporary-folder-for-current-user).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the temp file path with [`Path.GetTempPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx)