# Check directory, if not create it one line c#

Tags: c#

This my static Temp directory.

```
public static readonly string Temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\Quince\\";
```

Is it possible to check it in one line if directory is not, create it.

Comment: Of course it is, but why does it have to be a 'oneliner' ?
Also it is not clear if the check should happen only once, or every time the variable is accessed?

Comment: Directory.Exists("Folder Name")

Comment: In most cases, you should not be using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")` to get the temp path. [Use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/944533/3648487).

Comment: And use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) instead of string concat