# C# program closes immediately on friend's PC

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a C# program that copies a file and then reads certain parts of it. The program works perfectly fine on my pc, but on my friends pc it closes instantly. My friend has the latest .net framework version and the latest windows version.

This is my code:

```
while ( true )
{
  Console.WriteLine("");

  Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to check killer");
  Console.ReadLine();


  File.Copy(@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Local\DeadByDaylight\Saved\Logs\DeadByDaylight.log", "DeadByDaylightCopy.log", true);
  string killer = "";

  foreach ( string line in File.ReadAllLines("DeadByDaylightCopy.log") )
  {
    if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> TW") )
    {
      killer = "Wraith";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> TR") )
    {
      killer = "Trapper";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> HK") )
    {
      killer = "Spirit";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> MK") )
    {
      killer = "Plague";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> FK") )
    {
      killer = "Pig";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> OK") )
    {
      killer = "GhostFace";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> TN") )
    {
      killer = "Nurse";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> KK") )
    {
      killer = "Legion";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> BE") )
    {
      killer = "Huntress";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> TC") )
    {
      killer = "Billy";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> WI") )
    {
      killer = "Hag";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> GK") )
    {
      killer = "Clown";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> SD") )
    {
      killer = "Freddy";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> DO") )
    {
      killer = "Doctor";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> CA") )
    {
      killer = "Cannibal";
    }
    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> MM") )
    {
      killer = "Myers";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> UK") )
    {
      killer = "Deathslinger";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> SwedenKiller") )
    {
      killer = "Oni";
    }

    else if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> QK") )
    {
      killer = "Demogorgon";
    }

  }

  if ( killer == "" )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Make sure you're in the dedicated lobby");
  }

  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine(killer);
  }
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
  Console.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Classic programmer's issue :) Could any of the code be shared?
I assume you built the program with the same framework on your machine, right?

Comment: There is only 100.000.000 of possible reasons :) Can't you ask your friend for some logging information? Is that a Windows OS?

Comment: @SudipShrestha Just edited the post, thanks for the kind answer :)

Comment: Take all your code out. Write "hello" to the console. Does it work on your friend's pc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133199/net-global-exception-handler-in-console-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination folder is not set, so you can have problems with the starting directory or the working directory, as well as access rights, especially under Windows 10 even with an administrator user. This may raise an exception and immediately close the console.

You should use a folder in the user area as a target, dedicated for your application.

You can try that:

```
string pathCommon = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Local";

string pathSource = pathCommon + @"\DeadByDaylight\Saved\Logs\";
string pathDestination = pathCommon + @"\MyCompany-ChangeThisName\MyApp-ChangeThisName\";

string filenameSource = pathSource + "DeadByDaylight.log";
string filenameDestination = pathDestination + "DeadByDaylightCopy.log";

if ( !File.Exists(filenameSource) )
{
  Console.WriteLine("File not found: " + filenameSource);
  return;
}
else
{
  Directory.CreateDirectory(pathDestination);
  File.Copy(filenameSource, filenameDestination, true);
}
```

We created some vars, next we check if the source file exists or exit, then we create a destination folder to copy the file in.

For the user folder, a good practice is to use the assembly data if defined:

```
static public string UserDataFolderPath
{
  get
  {
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
                + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                + AssemblyCompany
                + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                + AssemblyTitle
                + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    return path;
  }
}
```

Having the `AssemblyInfo.cs` like:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Name of the app")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Any name as a root folder for your projects")]
```

Now you can write:

```
string pathDestination = UserDataFolderPath;
```

Also you can refactor your code and the tons of `if` by using a dictionary and a loop on, like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> RefTable = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  { "TW", "Wraith" },
  { "TR", "Trapper" },
  ...
};

// search for the first killer
foreach ( string line in File.ReadAllLines(filenameDestination) )
{
  foreach ( var item in RefTable )
    if ( line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> " + item.Key) )
    {
      killer = item.Value;
      break;
    }
  if (killer != "") break;
}

if ( killer == "" )
  Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Make sure you're in the dedicated lobby");
else
  Console.WriteLine(killer);
```

You can of course use the user temp folder instead of `UserDataFolderPath`:

[How to get temporary folder for current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944483/how-to-get-temporary-folder-for-current-user)